# Getting The Actual Video Label After Model.Predict Operations With 3DCNN Sequential Model

Tags: arguments, artificial-intelligence, prediction, evaluation, train-test-split

I have a challenge and I am trying to solve this in order to move forward, it is the final piece of the puzzle for my model operations.

**What I am trying to do?:***
is verify the videos that are being used in the Xval_test variable via the split operations here as per the example via here [In Python sklearn, how do I retrieve the names of samples/variables in test/training data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43946458/in-python-sklearn-how-do-i-retrieve-the-names-of-samples-variables-in-test-trai) :

```
X_train, Xval_test, Y_train, Yval_test = train_test_split(
        X, Y, train_size=0.8, test_size=0.2, random_state=1, shuffle=True)
```

**1.**
What I tried?:
is calling the name from the actual tag via file_path name, however that is not working. (every time the code runs the names from the file path are taken and not from the actual split operations Xval_test variable. This causes an issue during the model.fit() procedures as it changes the 1D flattened tensor to (a number of rows, 1 column)

```
file_paths = []
    for file_name in os.listdir(root):
        file_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            file_paths.append(file_path)
            print('**********************************************************')
            print('ALL Directory File Paths Completed', file_paths)
```

I am not sure if the files are being shuffled properly with my weak attempt as per the guidelines from the split() forum. (based on my knowledge, every time I run the code, those files would be shuffled to a new Xval_test set relative to it's specified split parameter 80:20.

**2.**
I tried calling the model.predict(), that presents no labels for which I was hoping that it did (maybe I am using it the wrong way for calling the indices, I don't know).

```
my_pred = model.predict(Xval_test).argmax(axis=1)
```

I tried calling np.argsmax():( I KNOW THE TOTAL AMT OF FILES IN Xval_test is 16 based on the split())

```
Y_valpred = np.argmax(model.predict(Xval_test), axis=1)  # model
```

This returns just the class label and not it's contents e.g. the classes in the datastore are folders containing (walking and fencing) rather than the actual video labels such as (walking0.avi....100/n and fencing0.avi.....100n/) !!!???!

I am not certain of the operation to get the folder content's tags, the actual file itself. It is this that I am trying to get from the X_test variable.

(or maybe its the wrong variable or functioning I using, again I am lacking the knowledge to understand this, please assist so that I can move to the next stage).

**3.**
I tried printing all of the variable's from the previous operations to see where that name tag would be stored and it is stored in the **name** variable below as per my operations: **(but how do I call these folder content's file tags forward to the X_test variable or as per my choice the model.predict() outputs in a column together with the other metrics. So far, this causes issues with the model.fit() function???)**

```
for files3 in files2:
            name = os.path.join(namelist, files3)
            name1 = name.strip("./dataset/")
            name2 = name1.strip("Fencing/")
            name3 = name2.strip("Stabing/")
            name3 = name3.replace('.av', '') 
            name4 = name3.split()
            # print("This is name1 ", name1)
            # name5 = pd.DataFrame({"vid_names": name4}).to_csv("results.csv")
            # name1 = name1.replace('[]', '') 
            with open('vid_names.csv', 'a',newline='') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer = writer.writerow(name4)
                # print("My Video Names => ", name3)
```

**3A.**
Thank you in advance, I am grateful for any guidance provided, Please assist!

**QUESTIONS:   ############################################**
**Ques: 1.**
Is it possible to see what video label tags are segmented within the X_Test Variable?

**Ques: 1A.**
If yes, may I request your guidance here, please, on how this can be done?:
I have been researching for weeks and cannot seem to get this sorted, your efforts would be greatly appreciated.

**Ques: 2. MY Expected OUTCOME:**
I am trying to access the prediction. So, In the end I would get an output relative to the actual video tag that insinuates the actual video that was used in the prediction operation along with its class tag (see below):

Initially, the model.predict() operations outputs numerical data relative to the class label.

I am trying to access the actual file label as well:
For example, what I want the predictions to look like is as follows:

```
        X_test_labs Pred_labs Actual_File     Pred_Score         
0         Fencing   Fencing   fencing0.avi    0.99650866
1         Walking   Fencing   walking6.avi    0.9948837   
2         Walking   Walking   walking21.avi   0.9967557
3         Fencing   Fencing   fencing32.avi   0.9930409
4         Walking   Fencing   walking43.avi   0.9961387
5         Walking   Walking   walking48.avi   0.6467387
6         Walking   Walking   walking50.avi   0.5465369
7         Walking   Walking   walking9.avi    0.3478027
8         Fencing   Fencing   fencing22.avi   0.1247543
9         Fencing   Fencing   fencing46.avi   0.7477777
10        Walking   Walking   walking37.avi   0.8499399
11        Fencing   Fencing   fencing19.avi   0.8887722
12        Walking   Walking   walking12.avi   0.7775351
13        Fencing   Fencing   fencing33.avi   0.4323323
14        Fencing   Fencing   fencing51.avi   0.7812434
15        Fencing   Fencing   fencing8.avi    0.8723476
```

**I am not sure how to achieve this task, this one is a little more tricky for me than anticipated**

**This is my code***

```
'''*******Load Dependencies********'''
from keras.regularizers import l2
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras_tqdm import TQDMNotebookCallback
from tqdm.keras import TqdmCallback
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import math
import tensorflow as tf
from tqdm import tqdm
import videoto3d
import seaborn as sns
import scikitplot as skplt
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score, classification_report, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
from keras.utils import np_utils
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.layers import (Activation, Conv3D, Dense, Dropout, Flatten,MaxPooling3D)
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import argparse
import time
import sys
import openpyxl
import os
import re
import csv
from keras import models
import cv2
import pickle
import glob
from numpy import load
    
np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')
print('**********************************************************')
print('Graphical Representation Of Accuracy & Validation Results Completed')

def plot_history(history, result_dir):
    plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], marker='.')
    plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], marker='.')
    plt.title('model accuracy')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.ylabel('accuracy')
    plt.grid()
    plt.legend(['Val_acc', 'Test_acc'], loc='lower right')
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(result_dir, 'model_accuracy.png'))
    plt.close()

    plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], marker='.')
    plt.plot(history.history['loss'], marker='.')
    plt.title('model Loss')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    plt.grid()
    plt.legend(['Val_loss', 'Test_loss'], loc='upper right')
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(result_dir, 'model_loss.png'))
    plt.close()

# Saving History Accuracy & Validation Acuuracy Results To Directory
print('**********************************************************')
print('Generating History Acuuracy Results Completed')
def save_history(history, result_dir):
    loss = history.history['loss']
    acc = history.history['accuracy']
    val_loss = history.history['val_loss']
    val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']
    nb_epoch = len(acc)

# Creating The Results File To Directory = Store Results
    print('**********************************************************')
    print('Saving History Acuuracy Results To Directory Completed')
    with open(os.path.join(result_dir, 'result.txt'), 'w') as fp:
        fp.write('epoch\tloss\tacc\tval_loss\tval_acc\n')

        # print(fp)
        for i in range(nb_epoch):
            fp.write('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(
                i, loss[i], acc[i], val_loss[i], val_acc[i]))

print('**********************************************************')
print('Loading All Specified Video Data Samples From Directory Completed')
def loaddata(video_dir, vid3d, nclass, result_dir, color=False, skip=True):
   
    files = os.listdir(video_dir)
    with open('files.csv', 'w') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow(files)
    root = '/Users/symbadian/3DCNN_latest_Version/3DCNNtesting/dataset/'
    dirlist = [item for item in os.listdir(
        root) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, item))]

    print('Get the filesname and path')
    print('DIRLIST Directory Completed', dirlist)
    file_paths = []
    for file_name in os.listdir(root):
        file_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            file_paths.append(file_path)
            print('**********************************************************')
            print('ALL Directory File Paths Completed', file_paths)

    roots, dirsy, fitte = next(os.walk(root), ([], [], []))
    print('**********************************************************')
    print('ALL Directory ROOTED', roots, fitte, dirsy)

    X = []
    print('X labels==>', X) # This stores all variable data in an object format 
    labellist = []
    pbar = tqdm(total=len(files))  # generate progress bar for file processing
    
    print('**********************************************************')
    print('Generating/Join Class Labels For Video Dataset For Input Completed')
    # Accessing files and labels from dataset directory 
    for filename in files:
        pbar.update(1)
        if filename == '.DS_Store':#.DS_Store
            continue

        namelist = os.path.join(video_dir, filename)
        files2 = os.listdir(namelist)
        
        ###############################################################################
        ######### NEEDS TO FIX THIS Data Adding to CSV Rather Than REWRITTING #########
        for files3 in files2:
            name = os.path.join(namelist, files3)

            #Call a function that extract the frames details of all file names 
            label = vid3d.get_UCF_classname(filename)
            if label not in labellist:
                if len(labellist) >= nclass:
                    continue
                labellist.append(label)  

            # This X variable is the point where the lables are store (I think??!?!)
            X.append(vid3d.video3d(name, color=color, skip=skip)) 
            
    pbar.close()

    # generating labellist/ writing to directory
    print('******************************************************')
    print('Saving All Class Labels For Referencing To Directory Completed')

    with open(os.path.join(result_dir, 'classes.txt'), 'w') as fp:
        for i in range(len(labellist)):
            # print('These are labellist i classes',i) #Not This 
            fp.write('{}\n'.format(labellist[i]))
            
    # print('These are my labels: ==>',mylabel)
    for num, label in enumerate(labellist):
        for i in range(len(labels)):
            if label == labels[i]:
                labels[i] = num
                # print('This is labels i',labels[i]) #Not this 
    if color:  # conforming image channels of image for input sequence
        return np.array(X).transpose((0, 2, 3, 4, 1)), labels
    else:
        return np.array(X).transpose((0, 2, 3, 1)), labels
        

print('**********************************************************')
print('Generating Args Informative Messages/ Tuning Parameters Options Completed')
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A 3D Convolution Model For Action Recognition')
    parser.add_argument('--batch', type=int, default=130)  
    parser.add_argument('--epoch', type=int, default=100)  
    parser.add_argument('--videos', type=str, default='dataset',help='Directory Where Videos Are Stored')# UCF101
    parser.add_argument('--nclass', type=int, default= 2)  
    parser.add_argument('--output', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--color', type=bool, default=False)
    parser.add_argument('--skip', type=bool, default=True)
    parser.add_argument('--depth', type=int, default=10) 
    args = parser.parse_args()
    # print('This is the Option Arguments ==>',args)
    
    print('**********************************************************')
    print('Specifying Input Size and Channels Completed')
    img_rows, img_cols, frames = 32, 32, args.depth
    channel = 3 if args.color else 1
    
    print('**********************************************************')
    print('Saving Dataset As NPZ To Directory Completed')
    fname_npz = 'dataset_{}_{}_{}.npz'.format(args.nclass, args.depth, args.skip)
    vid3d = videoto3d.Videoto3D(img_rows, img_cols, frames) 
    nb_classes = args.nclass
    
    # loading the data
    if os.path.exists(fname_npz):
        loadeddata = np.load(fname_npz)
        X, Y = loadeddata["X"], loadeddata["Y"]

    else:
        x, y = loaddata(args.videos, vid3d, args.nclass,args.output, args.color, args.skip)
        X = x.reshape((x.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, frames, channel))
        Y = np_utils.to_categorical(y, nb_classes)
        X = X.astype('float32')

        #save npzdata to file
        np.savez(fname_npz, X=X, Y=Y)
        print('Saved Dataset To dataset.npz. Completed')
    print('X_shape:{}\nY_shape:{}'.format(X.shape, Y.shape))
    
    print('**********************************************************')
    print('Initialise Model Layers & Layer Parameters Completed')
    # Sequential groups a linear stack of layers into a tf.keras.Model.
    # Sequential provides training and inference features on this model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv3D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),input_shape=(X.shape[1:]), padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv3D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'))

    model.add(Conv3D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv3D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'))

    model.add(Conv3D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv3D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(Conv3D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv3D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(Flatten())
    # Dense function to convert FCL to 512 values
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss=categorical_crossentropy,optimizer=Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    print('this is the model shape')
    model.output_shape
    plot_model(model, show_shapes=True,to_file=os.path.join(args.output, 'model.png'))

    print('**********************************************************')
    print("Train Test Method HoldOut Performance")
    X_train, Xval_test, Y_train, Yval_test = train_test_split(
        X, Y, train_size=0.8, test_size=0.2, random_state=1, stratify=Y, shuffle=True)

    print('**********************************************************')
    print('Deploying Data Fitting/ Performance Accuracy Guidance Completed')
    #Stop operations when experiencing no learning
    rlronp = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor="val_loss", factor=0.5, patience=1, mode='auto', min_delta=0.0001, cooldown=1, min_lr=0.0001)

    # Fit the training data
    history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_split=0.20, batch_size=args.batch,epochs=args.epoch, verbose=1, callbacks=[rlronp], shuffle=True)

    # Predict X_Test (Xval_test) data and Labels
    predict_labels = model.predict(Xval_test, batch_size=args.batch,verbose=1,use_multiprocessing=True)
    classes = np.argmax(predict_labels, axis = 1)
    label = np.argmax(Yval_test,axis = 1)
    
    print('This the BATCH size', args.batch)
    print('This the DEPTH size', args.depth)
    print('This the EPOCH size', args.epoch)
    print('This the TRAIN SPLIT size', len(X_train))
    print('This the TEST SPLIT size', len(Xval_test))

    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261597/keras-model-fit-verbose-formatting
    # A json file enhances the model performance by a simple to save/load model

    model_json = model.to_json()
    if not os.path.isdir(args.output):
        os.makedirs(args.output)
    with open(os.path.join(args.output, 'ucf101_3dcnnmodel.json'), 'w') as json_file:
        json_file.write(model_json)
        # hd5 contains multidimensional arrays of scientific data
    model.save_weights(os.path.join(args.output, 'ucf101_3dcnnmodel.hd5'))

    ''' Evaluation is a process
    '''
    print('**********************************************************')
    print('Displying Test Loss & Test Accuracy Completed')
    loss, acc = model.evaluate(Xval_test, Yval_test, verbose=2, batch_size=args.batch, use_multiprocessing=True)  # verbose 0
    
    print('this is args output', args.output)
    plot_history(history, args.output)
    save_history(history, args.output)
    print('**********************************************************')

    # Generating Picture Of Confusion matrix
    print('**********************************************************')
    print('Generating CM InputData/Classification Report Completed')
    
    #Ground truth (correct) target values.
    y_valtest_arg = np.argmax(Yval_test, axis=1)
    
    #Estimated targets as returned by a classifier
    Y_valpred = np.argmax(model.predict(Xval_test), axis=1)  # model
    print('y_valtest_arg Shape is ==>', y_valtest_arg.shape)
    print('Y_valpred Shape is ==>', Y_valpred.shape)

    print('**********************************************************')
    print('Classification_Report On Model Performance Completed==')
    print(classification_report(y_valtest_arg.round(), Y_valpred.round(), target_names=filehandle, zero_division=1))

    '''Intitate Confusion Matrix'''
    # print('Model Confusion Matrix Per Test Data Completed===>')
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_valtest_arg, Y_valpred, normalize=None)
    print('Display Confusion Matrix ===>', cm)
    print('**********************************************************')
    print('Model Overall Accuracy')
    print('Model Test loss:', loss)
    print('**********************************************************')
    print('Model Test accuracy:', acc)
    print('**********************************************************')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think the solution is around the prediction, train, test split and the evaluation arguments. However, I am lacking the knowledge to access the details required from the train, test, split(), if that's where the issue is.

I am really thankful for your guidance in advance, thanks a whole lot for clarifying this for me and closing the gaps in my understanding. really appreciate this!!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).